# USB visible in disk but not able to open

Tags: linux, usb, settings, ubuntu-18.04, disk

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVDYs.png)

As we can see in this image, 67 GB is shown is disk settings but is not detected by Ubuntu. How should I open it? What settings should I change so that my system detects this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount the USB because it is formatted in a format that is not supported by Ubuntu. There are however some packages that allow Ubuntu to mount exFAT drives:

```
# add-appt-repository universe
# apt update
# apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```